# How to populating a matrix using a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, matrix, ranking

So I am unsure as to why I am running into an issue for this very simple task. I have a list of lists called temp that is initialized like this:

`temp = [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '147', '148', '149', '150', '151', '152', '153', '154', '155', '156', '157', '158', '159', '160', '161', '162', '163', '164', '165', '166', '167', '168', '169', '170', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '177', '178', '179', '180', '181', '182', '183', '184', '185', '186', '187', '188', '189', '190', '191', '192', '193', '194', '195', '196', '197', '198', '199', '200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '207', '208', '209', '210', '211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', '229', '230', '231', '232', '233', '234', '235', '236', '237', '238', '239', '240\n'], ['11', '14', '16', '2', '10', '1', '4', '8', '26', '6', '5', '33', '41', '12', '53', '3', '7', '77', '9', '13', '21', '65', '60', '42', '35', '15', '17', '44', '22', '36', '75', '28', '20', '25', '56', '96', '24', '39', '18', '31', '38', '19', '34', '43', '32', '29', '46', '55', '37', '45', '30', '94', '51', '66', '89', '27', '49', '64', '48', '52', '50', '40', '23', '47', '72', '63', '69', '71', '208', '68', '74', '95', '59', '62', '86', '78', '70', '102', '129', '58', '67', '79', '101', '84', '73', '92', '76', '80', '57', '91', '82', '61', '88', '90', '93', '97', '103', '87', '134', '98', '99', '83', '113', '81', '111', '121', '135', '107', '117', '109', '105', '108', '104', '112', '100', '118', '110', '115', '128', '116', '85', '122', '133', '131', '119', '126', '124', '114', '179', '132', '210', '142', '152', '127', '155', '149', '120', '180', '141', '144', '139', '138', '130', '147', '240', '145', '185', '136', '173', '148', '143', '146', '162', '163', '137', '156', '188', '153', '157', '165', '154', '158', '160', '164', '175', '167', '159', '170', '150', '172', '166', '161', '182', '178', '183', '177', '184', '181', '151', '176', '187', '186', '169', '174', '190', '123', '194', '189', '196', '168', '204', '197', '200', '201', '195', '199', '198', '193', '192', '191', '202', '106', '206', '203', '125', '207', '218', '140', '205', '214', '221', '212', '217', '220', '209', '215', '216', '219', '224', '230', '213', '222', '223', '229', '227', '211', '225', '228', '226', '234', '232', '233', '231', '171', '235', '236', '238', '237', '239', '54\n'], ['114', '8', '94', '26', '33', '17', '14', '7', '64', '173', '4', '10', '11', '60', '41', '9', '53', '19', '42', '30', '52', '43', '49', '40', '21', '89', '37', '27', '29', '13', '34', '24', '95', '25', '39', '70', '63', '79', '75', '56', '77', '28', '69', '50', '73', '32', '101', '82', '72', '57', '96', '83', '88', '58', '61', '129', '109', '71', '120', '78', '76', '80', '87', '68', '98', '99', '110', '102', '115', '127', '118', '117', '104', '122', '138', '97', '133', '153', '137', '160', '126', '204', '128', '184', '234', '176', '131', '213', '85', '145', '177', '163', '152', '148', '189', '201', '183', '164', '168', '158', '150', '171', '162', '143', '172', '151', '161', '159', '211', '175', '141', '165', '200', '125', '219', '149', '155', '222', '202', '216', '209', '192', '182', '223', '212', '190', '224', '106', '215', '221', '205', '218', '236', '229', '225', '180', '198', '233', '231', '228', '232', '227', '235', '238', '237', '140', '239', '210', '217', '16', '23', '157', '170', '194', '185', '12', '119', '156', '92', '179', '6', '107', '44', '35', '20', '174', '103', '154', '147', '51', '67', '135', '191', '47', '2', '48', '214', '136', '197', '226', '100', '112', '134', '116', '208', '55', '187', '144', '3', '142', '1', '84', '15', '203', '123', '65', '186', '130', '46', '59', '36', '62', '18', '22', '81', '193', '169', '45', '206', '31', '105', '91', '132', '90', '178', '230', '146', '199', '66', '86', '121', '54', '74', '5', '108', '195', '188', '207', '167', '113', '93', '38', '111', '139', '220', '181', '196', '124', '166', '240\n'], ['1', '2', '33', '6', '4', '5', '7', '14', '12', '16', '8', '64', '11', '9', '17', '18', '20', '28', '13', '24', '19', '31', '21', '41', '40', '30', '22', '94', '35', '47', '27', '60', '25', '45', '34', '37', '29', '43', '69', '15', '3', '89', '65', '56', '53', '49', '38', '48', '42', '26', '59', '39', '72', '52', '129', '63', '10', '66', '67', '50', '23', '62', '79', '93', '36', '55', '82', '73', '78', '46', '32', '84', '57', '71', '54', '81', '98', '70', '58', '102', '88', '77', '90', '86', '104', '108', '95', '68', '96', '51', '101', '100', '75', '103', '80', '122', '99', '112', '92', '83', '135', '109', '105', '110', '115', '76', '61', '74', '117', '118', '179', '44', '128', '121', '120', '87', '126', '127', '114', '107', '133', '124', '134', '116', '111', '139', '113', '132', '130', '143', '138', '154', '91', '145', '240', '160', '148', '136', '119', '137', '153', '142', '173', '152', '97', '144', '159', '164', '162', '85', '131', '146', '157', '167', '174', '210', '156', '178', '188', '176', '158', '166', '170', '175', '169', '151', '204', '165', '147', '177', '172', '187', '183', '186', '181', '163', '189', '196', '149', '184', '191', '123', '180', '190', '168', '199', '155', '171', '106', '195', '201', '200', '192', '197', '150', '193', '209', '211', '203', '182', '205', '194', '202', '161', '206', '213', '207', '212', '214', '219', '208', '218', '217', '125', '216', '220', '215', '224', '221', '222', '230', '140', '185', '223', '231', '198', '225', '227', '234', '229', '228', '226', '233', '236', '235', '232', '141', '237', '238', '239\n']]`

I also have an empty matrix that has rows that are equal to the length of `temp[0]` and columns that are equal to the length of `temp` which in this case would be a 240x4 sized matrix.

Here is my current code to read over each list in temp, find the row that I want to populate which is equal to the value of the `list[i]-1` and set this row to the index which is `i`. I am only doing this for the first column as of now.

```
for test in temp:
   for i in range(len(test)):
      #print("Entry: (" + str(test[i]) + ",0) populated with index: " + str(i+1))
      row = int(test[i])-1
      val = i+1
      matrix[row][0] = val
```

I would expect the first column of `matrix` to just be 1, 2,...,240. However after printing out `matrix` I get the following:

`matrix = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [41, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0], [6, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0], [7, 0, 0, 0], [11, 0, 0, 0], [14, 0, 0, 0], [57, 0, 0, 0], [13, 0, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0, 0], [19, 0, 0, 0], [8, 0, 0, 0], [40, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [15, 0, 0, 0], [16, 0, 0, 0], [21, 0, 0, 0], [17, 0, 0, 0], [23, 0, 0, 0], [27, 0, 0, 0], [61, 0, 0, 0], [20, 0, 0, 0], [33, 0, 0, 0], [50, 0, 0, 0], [31, 0, 0, 0], [18, 0, 0, 0], [37, 0, 0, 0], [26, 0, 0, 0], [22, 0, 0, 0], [71, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0], [35, 0, 0, 0], [29, 0, 0, 0], [65, 0, 0, 0], [36, 0, 0, 0], [47, 0, 0, 0], [52, 0, 0, 0], [25, 0, 0, 0], [24, 0, 0, 0], [49, 0, 0, 0], [38, 0, 0, 0], [112, 0, 0, 0], [34, 0, 0, 0], [70, 0, 0, 0], [30, 0, 0, 0], [48, 0, 0, 0], [46, 0, 0, 0], [60, 0, 0, 0], [90, 0, 0, 0], [54, 0, 0, 0], [45, 0, 0, 0], [75, 0, 0, 0], [66, 0, 0, 0], [44, 0, 0, 0], [73, 0, 0, 0], [79, 0, 0, 0], [51, 0, 0, 0], [32, 0, 0, 0], [107, 0, 0, 0], [62, 0, 0, 0], [56, 0, 0, 0], [12, 0, 0, 0], [43, 0, 0, 0], [58, 0, 0, 0], [59, 0, 0, 0], [88, 0, 0, 0], [39, 0, 0, 0], [78, 0, 0, 0], [74, 0, 0, 0], [53, 0, 0, 0], [68, 0, 0, 0], [108, 0, 0, 0], [93, 0, 0, 0], [106, 0, 0, 0], [82, 0, 0, 0], [69, 0, 0, 0], [63, 0, 0, 0], [95, 0, 0, 0], [76, 0, 0, 0], [67, 0, 0, 0], [100, 0, 0, 0], [72, 0, 0, 0], [150, 0, 0, 0], [84, 0, 0, 0], [116, 0, 0, 0], [81, 0, 0, 0], [42, 0, 0, 0], [83, 0, 0, 0], [133, 0, 0, 0], [99, 0, 0, 0], [64, 0, 0, 0], [28, 0, 0, 0], [87, 0, 0, 0], [89, 0, 0, 0], [145, 0, 0, 0], [77, 0, 0, 0], [97, 0, 0, 0], [92, 0, 0, 0], [91, 0, 0, 0], [80, 0, 0, 0], [94, 0, 0, 0], [85, 0, 0, 0], [103, 0, 0, 0], [189, 0, 0, 0], [120, 0, 0, 0], [86, 0, 0, 0], [102, 0, 0, 0], [104, 0, 0, 0], [125, 0, 0, 0], [98, 0, 0, 0], [127, 0, 0, 0], [119, 0, 0, 0], [105, 0, 0, 0], [124, 0, 0, 0], [109, 0, 0, 0], [110, 0, 0, 0], [139, 0, 0, 0], [115, 0, 0, 0], [114, 0, 0, 0], [96, 0, 0, 0], [182, 0, 0, 0], [122, 0, 0, 0], [214, 0, 0, 0], [117, 0, 0, 0], [118, 0, 0, 0], [113, 0, 0, 0], [55, 0, 0, 0], [129, 0, 0, 0], [151, 0, 0, 0], [128, 0, 0, 0], [121, 0, 0, 0], [123, 0, 0, 0], [101, 0, 0, 0], [138, 0, 0, 0], [140, 0, 0, 0], [131, 0, 0, 0], [126, 0, 0, 0], [222, 0, 0, 0], [237, 0, 0, 0], [142, 0, 0, 0], [130, 0, 0, 0], [146, 0, 0, 0], [134, 0, 0, 0], [152, 0, 0, 0], [169, 0, 0, 0], [137, 0, 0, 0], [179, 0, 0, 0], [195, 0, 0, 0], [166, 0, 0, 0], [144, 0, 0, 0], [141, 0, 0, 0], [132, 0, 0, 0], [187, 0, 0, 0], [157, 0, 0, 0], [153, 0, 0, 0], [161, 0, 0, 0], [147, 0, 0, 0], [136, 0, 0, 0], [204, 0, 0, 0], [149, 0, 0, 0], [176, 0, 0, 0], [148, 0, 0, 0], [168, 0, 0, 0], [162, 0, 0, 0], [154, 0, 0, 0], [185, 0, 0, 0], [165, 0, 0, 0], [163, 0, 0, 0], [188, 0, 0, 0], [171, 0, 0, 0], [143, 0, 0, 0], [155, 0, 0, 0], [164, 0, 0, 0], [160, 0, 0, 0], [170, 0, 0, 0], [158, 0, 0, 0], [111, 0, 0, 0], [183, 0, 0, 0], [175, 0, 0, 0], [200, 0, 0, 0], [173, 0, 0, 0], [180, 0, 0, 0], [223, 0, 0, 0], [174, 0, 0, 0], [172, 0, 0, 0], [159, 0, 0, 0], [177, 0, 0, 0], [184, 0, 0, 0], [181, 0, 0, 0], [193, 0, 0, 0], [196, 0, 0, 0], [202, 0, 0, 0], [190, 0, 0, 0], [178, 0, 0, 0], [194, 0, 0, 0], [226, 0, 0, 0], [186, 0, 0, 0], [192, 0, 0, 0], [191, 0, 0, 0], [203, 0, 0, 0], [199, 0, 0, 0], [167, 0, 0, 0], [201, 0, 0, 0], [205, 0, 0, 0], [207, 0, 0, 0], [211, 0, 0, 0], [197, 0, 0, 0], [156, 0, 0, 0], [198, 0, 0, 0], [208, 0, 0, 0], [206, 0, 0, 0], [209, 0, 0, 0], [217, 0, 0, 0], [215, 0, 0, 0], [213, 0, 0, 0], [212, 0, 0, 0], [210, 0, 0, 0], [216, 0, 0, 0], [219, 0, 0, 0], [220, 0, 0, 0], [224, 0, 0, 0], [218, 0, 0, 0], [227, 0, 0, 0], [232, 0, 0, 0], [228, 0, 0, 0], [231, 0, 0, 0], [230, 0, 0, 0], [221, 0, 0, 0], [225, 0, 0, 0], [236, 0, 0, 0], [233, 0, 0, 0], [229, 0, 0, 0], [235, 0, 0, 0], [234, 0, 0, 0], [238, 0, 0, 0], [239, 0, 0, 0], [240, 0, 0, 0], [135, 0, 0, 0]]`

For some reason column 0 is not following the 1,2,...,240 that I would expect. If the for loop is just going from 0...240 I thought it would be fairly simple to just set the row to that index. I would expect row 3 for example to have a 3 now in the first column, not a 41. Are there any suggestions to fix this?

Here is a smaller test case:

```
matrix = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
temp = [[1,2,3,4,5], [5,4,3,2,1],[1,4,5,3,2]]
for test in temp:
    for i in range(len(test)):
        #print("Entry: (" + str(test[i]) + ",0) populated with index: " + str(i+1))
        row = int(test[i])-1
        val = i+1
        matrix[row][0] = val
print(matrix)
```

This outputs:

`matrix = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

I would expect the first col. to be 1,2,3,4,5 but it is instead 1,5,4,2,3.

Comment: Could you reproduce this with a smaller matrix?  I have a pretty good idea of what's wrong with your code (you have two nested loops when you're theoretically trying to just change one column), but it's hard to verify by looking at the data/output when it's a thousand lines long.

Comment: @Samwise Just updated thee question with a small test case, there is still an issue it seems.

Comment: "I also have an empty matrix that has rows that are equal to the length of temp[0] and columns that are equal to the length of temp which in this case would be a 240x4 sized matrix." - should't matrix in the smaller test case be 5x3 instead of 5x5?

Comment: Why do you expect the first column to be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?  Are you just trying to transpose `temp`?  You can do that with a one-liner: `matrix = [list(t) for t in zip(*temp)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all those nested loops with inconvenient index adjustments and conversions using `numpy` array with short and flexible array indexing:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
temp = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [5,4,3,2,1], [1,4,5,3,2]])

matrix[:, 0] = temp[0]
print(matrix)
```

---

```
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [2 0 0 0 0]
 [3 0 0 0 0]
 [4 0 0 0 0]
 [5 0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is basically transpose the original matrix. If that is the case, you can just use numpy transpose function:

```
import numpy as np

temp = [[1,2,3,4,5], [5,4,3,2,1],[1,4,5,3,2]]

temp_np = np.array(temp)
result_np = temp_np.T
result = result_np.tolist()
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 5, 1], [2, 4, 4], [3, 3, 5], [4, 2, 3], [5, 1, 2]]
```